# How can i detect multiLanguages in string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, unicode, cultureinfo

I have a string in **c#**

How can i detect if this string contains **Chars** from **Different** Languages ?

i.e : a person fills his **english** name in text box and **also** his **local** language name.

I want to disallow that.

something like this :

> "check the language table of the chars in the string and if it comes
>   from different unicode tables - return ERROR".

but i think there is a problem for '**a**' in **us** or **uk**.

maybe im wrong.

how can i recognize more than one language ?

Comment: you mean *language*, *charset* or *culture info*? What platform do you use? ASP.NET of winforms or silverlight? Where does your application will be installed? What is the essence of the regex and the unicode tag?

Comment: Not all chars belong to a specific language. You will need a much stronger definition of your problem.

Comment: @ Caspar Kleijne  , thanks I added asp.net. its a web site which has a textbox that should contain only one language chars.

Comment: @ Henk Holterman  , so what do you suggest? I want to allow only one language...

Comment: It's your problem, you will need to define it. You might get some better answers by giving more and _much better_ examples. And when you want to alert somebody, don't put a space after '@'.

Comment: @Henk Holterman ,  i didnt know about the space part. and here is the example : "abdאבג"...... this string contains hebrew and english chars. i want to disallow that. it can be hebrew and other language. i think im very clear about that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're searching for codepoints. The unique identifiers of a character in codepage. I think this should be useful to you [How would you get an array of Unicode code points from a .NET String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687359/how-would-you-get-an-array-of-unicode-code-points-a-net-string). Once you get codepoints array from the string, you can check it against the range of code points you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried .  i can figure it out - how do i see if the string contains more than 1 language? can you please explain ?

Comment: Well, if you talking about natural language detection,there is no easy solution, you will need a dictionary of language and try to figure out more or less like modern browsers do. This is a complex. What you can do, is to create a set of numbers devided by alphabets (latin, arabic, hindu, russian) and identify the presence of different APHABETS but not LANGUAGES. In other words if I write a sentence in France mixed with Italian, you will never figure out (if I didn't use language specific letters), but you can defer: latin languages from non latin ones.

Comment: , thanks how do i defer Latin vs not Latin ? can you reference me to some example?

Comment: I think you can look here for distribution of codes: http://inamidst.com/stuff/unidata/