# Return code point of characters in C#

Tags: c#, unicode, unicode-string

How can I return the [Unicode Code Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) of a character? For example, if the input is "A", then the output should be "U+0041". Ideally, a solution should take care of [surrogate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates).

With *code point* I mean the actual code point [according to Unicode](http://unicode.org/glossary/#code_point), which is different from *[code unit](http://unicode.org/glossary/#code_unit)* (UTF8 has 8-bit code units, UTF16 has 16-bit code units and UTF32 has 32-bit code units, in the latter case the value is equal to the code point, after taking endianness into account).

Comment: This question is severely misworded. “Returning the ‘Unicode’ of a character” has no meaning, and frankly, is nonsense. Your example makes clear what you actually want, but the title needs to be reworked. Please do so.

Comment: Thanks. I have given you my upvote in appreciation.

Comment: Note that "UTF8 has 8-bit code units, UTF16 has 16-bit code units" isn't quite correct. Both UTF-8 and UTF-16 are variable length. UTF-8 can be between 1-4 bytes depending on the code point. It is designed to be backwards compatible with ASCII, but for characters outside of that, it needs either 2 or 4 bytes. Similarly, UTF-16 uses either 2 or 4 bytes. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Easy, since chars in C# is actually UTF16 code points:

```
char x = 'A';
Console.WriteLine("U+{0:x4}", (int)x);
```

To address the comments, A `char` in C# is a 16 bit number, and holds a UTF16 code point. Code points above 16 the bit space cannot be represented in a C# character. Characters in C# is not variable width. A *string* however can have 2 chars following each other, each being a code unit, forming a UTF16 code point. If you have a string input and characters above the 16 bit space, you can use `char.IsSurrogatePair` and `Char.ConvertToUtf32`, as suggested in another answer:

```
string input = ....
for(int i = 0 ; i < input.Length ; i += Char.IsSurrogatePair(input,i) ? 2 : 1)
{
    int x = Char.ConvertToUtf32(input, i);
    Console.WriteLine("U+{0:X4}", x);
}
```

Comment: They are unicode code units, not code points. What about characters that require more than one code unit?

Comment: @driis... Same as  GregS comment

Comment: @GregS: Can a `char` actually hold a character that requires more than one code unit?

Comment: @GregS: Please see updated answer. My solution yields exactly the same result as the other (upvoted) answer, it just doesn't jump through as many hoops to get there.

Comment: @driis: I didn't downvote you, I was just offering a clarifying point.

Comment: @dtb: no. I meant Unicode characters, not Char characters. I hate the whole Unicode terminology as it seems designed to confuse people. I still think this answer has "point" and "unit" swapped.

Comment: @Qaesar lower case a (`'a'`) is `U+0061`, uppercase a (`'A'`) is `U+0041`

Comment: @GregS A codepoint is an abstract, logical character, one divorced from its low-level physical layout. 99.99% of programmers want to work only with logical characters, not individual physical constituent components that are laid out differently on different sytsems.  That means that a code unit is the ugly thing you never want to deal with.  You only want to deal with code points.

Comment: @ All, I just want to know, which of ASCII or code point the processor considers it when it looks up for the letters?? I:m really getting confused. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry if we are confusing you. The problem is Unicode encodings is actually a bit complex even though they might not seem so at first glance. The code in this answer, or the one @dtb posted, will work fine for you. I can recommend http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html if you want some more background.

Comment: @ driis. I have to say sorry because I bothered you . Your Kind action really appreciated. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

The following code writes the codepoints of a `string` input to the console:

```
string input = "\uD834\uDD61";

for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i += char.IsSurrogatePair(input, i) ? 2 : 1)
{
    var codepoint = char.ConvertToUtf32(input, i);

    Console.WriteLine("U+{0:X4}", codepoint);
}
```

*Output:*

```
U+1D161
```

Since strings in .NET are UTF-16 encoded, the `char` values that make up the string need to be converted to UTF-32 first.

Comment: That doesn't convert to UTF-32 but returns the code point as integer, UTF-32 is an encoding, not an integer. This method naming propagates same confusion as microsoft labeling the UTF-16LE encoding as "unicode"

Comment: @Esailija: I wasn't sure what is more confusing: converting to a Unicode code point using a method named `ConvertToUtf32`, or converting to UTF-32 and treating the result as Unicode code point. In the end that's probably splitting hairs.

Comment: you can't treat the result of converting to actual UTF-32 as code point, you need to decode the code points from the encoding, just like you would decode from UTF-16 or UTF-8, except simpler. But I can see why this would be seen nitpicky :P

Answer (score 12):

In .NET Core 3.0 or later, you can use the [Rune Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.rune):

```
// Note that  and  are encoded using surrogate pairs
// but A, B, C and ✋ are not
var runes = "ABC✋".EnumerateRunes();

foreach (var r in runes)
    Console.Write($"U+{r.Value:X4} ");
        
// Writes: U+0041 U+0042 U+0043 U+270B U+1F609 U+1F44D
```

Answer (score 4):

C# cannot store unicode codepoints in a `char`, as `char` is only 2 bytes and unicode codepoints routinely exceed that length. The solution is to either represent a codepoint as a sequence of bytes (either as a byte array or "flattened" into a 32-bit primitive) or as a string. The accepted answer converts to UTF32, but that's not always ideal.

This is the code we use to split a string into its unicode codepoint components, but preserving the native UTF-16 encoding. The result is an enumerable that can be used to compare (sub)strings natively in C#/.NET:

```
    public class InvalidEncodingException : System.Exception
    { }

    public static IEnumerable<string> UnicodeCodepoints(this string s)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (Char.IsSurrogate(s[i]))
            {
                if (s.Length < i + 2)
                {
                    throw new InvalidEncodingException();
                }
                yield return string.Format("{0}{1}", s[i], s[++i]);
            }
            else
            {
                yield return string.Format("{0}", s[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is some merit in @Yogendra Singh 's answer, currently the only one with negative voting.
The job can be done like this

```
    public static IEnumerable<int> Utf8ToCodePoints(this string s)
    {
        var utf32Bytes = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(s);
        var bytesPerCharInUtf32 = 4;
        Debug.Assert(utf32bytes.Length % bytesPerCharInUtf32 == 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < utf32bytes.Length; i+= bytesPerCharInUtf32)
        {
            yield return BitConverter.ToInt32(utf32bytes, i);
        }
    }
```

Tested with

```
    var surrogatePairInput = "abc";
    Debug.Assert(surrogatePairInput.Length == 5);
    var pointsAsString = string.Join(";" , 
        surrogatePairInput
        .Utf8ToCodePoints()
        .Select(p => $"U+{p:X4}"));
    Debug.Assert(pointsAsString == "U+0061;U+0062;U+0063;U+1F4A9");
```

Example is relevant because the pile of poo is represented as a surrogate pair.

Comment: As a point of improvement  rather than getting the utf8 bytes and then converting them to utf32 you could just get the utf32 bytes in the first place.

Comment: Also the reason that the answer you mentioned has a negative score is that the method only accepts a `char` as a parameter which means it could never give you more than two bytes of information. Yours is a vast improvement because you actually parse a string and not a char.

Comment: Thanks @Chris. I simplified the method.

Answer (score -1):

I found a little method on [msdn forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/1eee1666-6048-4558-84f1-86976baf0c41). Hope this helps.

```
    public int get_char_code(char character){ 
        UTF32Encoding encoding = new UTF32Encoding(); 
        byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(character.ToString().ToCharArray()); 
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0); 
    }
```

Comment: Does this ever return something different than `(int)character`? What happens if `character` is one half of a surrogate pair?

Comment: @dtb (very late answer, I know). The interesting thing of this code is that it shows using `UTF32Encoding`, but since the method only takes a `char`, it has no effect and is the same as `(int) character`, though much slower than a cast. In fact, `character.ToString().ToCharArray()` will always return an array of one item (size 2 bytes), and the `BitConverter` will never return a value > 65535. Nice idea in principle, but useless in the way it is presented.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static string ToCodePointNotation(char c)
{

    return "U+" + ((int)c).ToString("X4");
}

Console.WriteLine(ToCodePointNotation('a')); //U+0061
```

Comment: @Qaesar lower case a (`'a'`) is `U+0061`, uppercase a (`'A'`) is `U+0041`

Comment: You should throw an exception if `Char.IsSurrogate(c)` because such a code unit cannot be considered a codepoint value and therefore doesn't have a codepoint notation.

Comment: This answer is simply not correct, you cannot presume there exists a one-to-one mapping between a C# `char` and a UTF-16 codepoint because there is none.