# How can I escape text values to their codepoints using Newtonsoft Json?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I'm developing an Arabic JSON service and I'm using the Newtonsoft Json library.
I was wondering if there's a way to convert a string to it's codepoint representation like "\u005C"

Currently I'm using the JsonConverter

```
Response.Filter = new DeflateStream(Response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "deflate");
Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders["Accept-encoding"] = true;
Response.ContentEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
Response.ContentType = "application/json";
Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.None));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually loop through the string's characters and convert them. Like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13894030).