# How do you convert a single Unicode code point to a string at runtime?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have the following code point: `u1F64A` (which is the  emoji).

This can be written as:

```cs
string monkey = "\u1F64A";
```

How would I convert a known codepoint (as an integer) to a string at runtime though?

```cs
int codepoint = 0xF64A;
string monkey = //?
```

Answer (score 4):

When I want to play with Emojis in C#, I build a helper class just like this:

```cs
public class Emoji
{
    readonly int[] codes;
    public Emoji(int[] codes)
    {
        this.codes = codes;
    }

    public Emoji(int code)
    {
        codes = new int[] { code };
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (codes == null)
            return string.Empty;

        var sb = new StringBuilder(codes.Length);

        foreach (var code in codes)
            sb.Append(Char.ConvertFromUtf32(code));

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

This way, I can just do `string monkeyEmoji = new Emoji(0xF64A);`

It also supports emojis with multiple code points (yes, those exist and are a pain)

Answer (score 1):

Is the above code even compilable? It doesn't compile on my machine.
And why should it, `\u1F64A` is not a valid string.

I think what could work is `string monkey = $"{char.ConvertToUtf32((char) 0xF64, 'A')}"`, but that is just a guess. I just answered to clarify that the first line of code you wrote is not compilable on my machine.

Comment: based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894021/return-code-point-of-characters-in-c-sharp

Comment: Edited to flank `\u1F64A` with single quotes