# Using supplemental Unicode characters as char literals in C#

Tags: c#, unicode

Is there a way to use supplemental Unicode characters (for example `''`) as char literals in C#? I tried it in VS 2017, with the source file saved as UTF-8 with BOM, UTF-16 LE and BE and I always get the error `Too many characters in character literal`.

Comment: The `char` type is effectively a single utf-16 code point. If the character is not a single utf-16 code point then no.

Comment: FWIW it is possible to represent it as a string, `"\uD83C\uDCDC"`.

Comment: @mikez Note: It's not necessary to use the \u notation.

Comment: @mikez: Or just use `\U` instead: `"\U0001F0DC"`

Comment: @TomBlodget: It's not *necessary*, but it does mean you don't need to worry about encodings as much, if all your source code is ASCII.

Comment: @JonSkeet I wouldn't do that with source code files because that could lead to making the same assumption about other text files—and that just won't do.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any language that treats codepoints as first class concepts?

Comment: @TomBlodget: The difference is that I control how I treat other source files in my code, whereas it can (depending on platform etc) be slightly trickier - or at least annoying - to persuade all tools everywhere to handle source code as UTF-8.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, we do put up with cases of "the cobbler's children have no shoes" in our work. I've been lucky enough to be dogmatic with character encodings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `char` is one UTF-16 code unit. `String` is a sequence of UTF-16 code units so if you have a codepoint that UTF-16 encodes as two code units, use a `String` literal.

```
""
```

Comment: Right, I was just reading about how to get the codepoints out from a string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687359/how-would-you-get-an-array-of-unicode-code-points-from-a-net-string